# vista de lectura en la Web

Tags: html5

como puedo activar el modo lectura a mi Pagina web 
es una configuracion o un meta ?

Para que aparesca este icono en la barra de busqueda de los navegadores

[image: Vista Lectura]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas usar al menos un tag `<p>` alrededor de algun texto y 516 caracteres en 7 palabras

```
<body>
  <p>
    123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
    123456789 123456
  </p>
</body>
```

Información extraída de este [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661650/how-does-firefox-reader-view-operate/30688312#30688312)

Comment: tengo integrado angular y coloque el parrafo pero aun a si no me muestra el icono.